Can you cut a large branch off an old conifer hedge without killing the plant?
I have a conifer plan that I want to keep alive but also build a shed near it, I was wondering if I could cut off it's largest branch to make room while keeping it alive?

A picture would help a ton!

What percentage of the plant's foliage is on the branch you plan to remove?

It is possible to cut a large branch off an old conifer hedge without killing the plant. However, there are some important things that you should keep in mind  such as -

Timing: Only prune the plant in its dormant period.
Technique: Use sharp tools and make a clean cut just outside of the collar of the branch where it is attached to the trunk.
Portion: Only cut under 25% of the plant in one season to avoid plant stress.
Post-pruning care: Make sure that you provide all the things that your plant requires i.e. adequate watering, nutrition, sunlight, etc.

By following these guidelines you can prune your plant and avoid any major damage. Hope this helped!

I appreciate your answer greatly, some of that I definitely didn't know.
